# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String'

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a property of type byte[]

```
byte[] _signature;
    public byte[] Signature
    {
        get { return _signature; }
        set
        {
            if (_signature != value)
            {
                _signature = value;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged("Signature");

            }
        }
    }
```

When set value to this

```
System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(openfile.FileName);
                //covert image to base64 and save to sign
SignaturePath = openfile.FileName;
Signature = ImageTobyte(img, img.RawFormat);

....
private byte[] ImageTobyte(System.Drawing.Image image, ImageFormat format)
    {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Convert Image to byte[]
            image.Save(ms, format);
            byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

            return imageBytes;
        }
    }
```

I get error in `Signature = ImageTobyte(img, img.RawFormat);` :Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: Doesn't the debugger tell you which line the exception is thrown at?

Comment: Signature = ImageTobyte(img, img.RawFormat);

Comment: Everything is right here. It must work, if Signature is byte[].

Comment: Yes, but i don't understand why i get error :(

Comment: @Sam : runtime error.

Comment: The method is accurate and producing no errors. Check where you did binding of your Signature property, because when you set Signature the RaisePropertyChanged is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you must be binding a string type with your byte[] type Signature property.